# flutter - App bar scrolling with overlapping content in Flexible space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-animation

i am trying to recreate App bar scrolling with overlapping content in Flexible space using flutter.

the behavior is demonstrated here:

http://karthikraj.net/2016/12/24/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android/

**I created collapsing AppBar using SliverAppBar already, using the code I pasted here, I am trying to create [THIS](http://karthikraj.net/assets/scrolling/flexiSpaceContentOverlapping.gif)**

i cant use Stack for it because i cant find any onScroll callback, so far i created appbar with flexibleSpace, the app bar collapse on scroll:

```
Scaffold(
    body: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) => <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                  pinned: true,
                  expandedHeight: 180.0,
                ),
              ],
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
              "Item $index",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

[image: What i created so far]

edit: [Example of what i want to create](http://karthikraj.net/assets/scrolling/flexiSpaceContentOverlapping.gif)

Comment: Could you achieve this? I'm trying to do exactly same kinda effect and it's not happening smoothly. If you have achieved by the time can you share some hints?

Answer (score 3):

ScrollViews take a ScrollController which is a Listenable that notifies on scroll offset updates.

You can listen to the ScrollController and use a Stack to achieve the effect you're interested in based on the scroll offset.

Here's a quick example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scroll demo',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(elevation: 0.0),
        body: new CustomScroll(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new CustomScrollState();
}

class CustomScrollState extends State<CustomScroll> {
  ScrollController scrollController;
  double offset = 0.0;
  static const double kEffectHeight = 100.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
      children: <Widget> [
        new Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: (kEffectHeight - offset * 0.5).clamp(0.0, kEffectHeight),
        ),
        new Positioned(
          child: new Container(
            width: 200.0,
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: buildListItem,
              controller: scrollController,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildListItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Text('Item $index')
    );
  }

  void updateOffset() {
    setState(() {
      offset = scrollController.offset;
    }); 
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = new ScrollController();
    scrollController.addListener(updateOffset);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    scrollController.removeListener(updateOffset);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should also take a look at https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

Comment: hi
i am trying to create [this](http://karthikraj.net/assets/scrolling/flexiSpaceContentOverlapping.gif)

Answer (score -1):

I think the `SliverAppbar` widget is what you are looking for.

Take a look at this article which shows you how to achieve your goal.

https://flutterdoc.com/animating-app-bars-in-flutter-cf034cd6c68b

Comment: thanks for your help but its not what i need i seen that article
what i made now does it already, [that's what i am trying to achieve](http://karthikraj.net/assets/scrolling/flexiSpaceContentOverlapping.gif)