# how to make sliverheader overlap sliverappbar

Tags: flutter

[Flutter SliverList Overlap on SliverAppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64243635/flutter-sliverlist-overlap-on-sliverappbar)

Anyone help me to code like this link stackoverflow. I don't know what is

topBarFactor +_topBarHeight

I already searched how about it but I have anything

Comment: you have to try to do it yourself first. Then if you get stuck, come back here and show your code. without your code, we cant help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.