# Flutter - overlay above my Fab and TabBar on scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of `Card` with dynamic height and I need to put them in an `OverlayEntry` which is floating on bottom of those cards.

The problem is there, the OverlayEntry works perfectly but maybe a little bit more then I expected. Why does it overlay the `FloatingActionButton` and the `TabBar` as well ?

I expected that's a problem with the elevation, then I tried to put my fab into a `Material` widget and set the elevation to some abusive value and it doesn't work...

Does I need to set the Z axis (and how ? I'm not sure that using the `Transform` widget is a good idea...) and then put the Fab and TabBar above the `OverlayEntry` or is there an other alternative for my solution ?

Have a look for more details : https://pastebin.com/pzhyaQfP

The screenshots follows.

If someone can help me, you will be my savior ;)

[image: before scrolling]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this?](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: Actually it was my first choice but I can't because I need the RenderBox of the card beyond and for that I need to create the "I'm a stick card" after the first build.

Comment: Crap you'r right ! I don't know why I didn't think to set te position "bottom: 0" instead calculate the height from the "top"...
Thank you, but the question still for the Overlay, how can I show my in a lower lvl then the Navigator, which is on top of the app and then cover the appbar and fab ?

Comment: Oh I see. Try the [ScrollviewWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51511035/6301103)